# Merging two lists: I have hardcoded two list and want to print both the list data where the condition match. Please let me know how can I do?

Tags: c#, list, linq, arraylist, foreach

Merging two lists: I have hardcoded two lists and want to print both the list data where the conditions match. Please let me know how can I do?

I tried to use LINQ and got the solution but need to solve using for loop, please advise on the same.

```
    public IActionResult GetAllVehicleDrivers()
    {
        var VehicleList = new List<Vehicle>()

        {
            new Vehicle() { VehNum = "KA04AS1234", VehId = 1 },
            new Vehicle() { VehNum = "KA04AS5689", VehId = 2 },
            new Vehicle() { VehNum = "KA04AS9874", VehId = 3 },
            new Vehicle() { VehNum = "KA04AS5647", VehId = 4 },
            new Vehicle() { VehNum = "KA04AS7452", VehId = 5 },
        };

        var DriverList = new List<Driver>()
        {
            new Driver() { DriverName = "Gajaraj", DriverId = 123,  VehId = 1 },
            new Driver() { DriverName = "Tajar", DriverId = 245,  VehId = 5 },
            new Driver() { DriverName = "Pajara", DriverId = 363,  VehId = 3 },
            new Driver() { DriverName = "Haja", DriverId = 425,  VehId = 2 },
            new Driver() { DriverName = "Kaj", DriverId = 547,  VehId = 4 },
            new Driver() { DriverName = "Dajarajines", DriverId = 547,  VehId = 1 },
        };

        foreach (var i in VehicleList)
        {
            foreach (var j in DriverList)
            {
                if (i.VehId == j.VehId)
                {
                    List<dynamic> VehDriverList = new List<dynamic>()
                    {              i.VehId,
                                   i.VehNum,
                                   j.DriverId,
                                   j.DriverName
                    };
                    return Ok(VehDriverList);
                }
                else

                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your nested loop structure is incorrect, having the return statement inside the loop, immediately returns from the action method, also instantiating the List<> inside the loop, overrides the previous collection over and over. So, how about this?

```
// initialize the List outside the nested loop
List<dynamic> VehDriverList = new List<dynamic>();

foreach (var i in VehicleList)
{
    foreach (var j in DriverList)
    {
        if (i.VehId == j.VehId)
        {
            VehDriverList.Add(new List<dynamic>()
                {
                    i.VehId,
                    i.VehNum,
                    j.DriverId,
                    j.DriverName
                });
        }
    }
}

// return the results outside the loops
if (VehDriverList.Any())
{
    return Ok(VehDriverList);
}

return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: p.s. I would personally create a view model / DTO, e.g. VehicleDriver, instead of using dynamic. dynamic is good for situations that you don't know the properties, e.g. interoperability with COM objects, but here you are very aware of what you properties you want to return.

Comment: Is there any way to access the data of VehDriverList data in another Getby Id method and access the driver details?

Comment: @Gopal, while you could by using Sessions (Store the VehDriverList in the Session object and Retrieve it in your GetById() action method), that's not the best way to go. If you are using Repository pattern to access data, if it's retrieving the data from a database, your GetById() should get the details from your repository directly, and if the data is in-memory (the way your List<Vehicle> and List<Driver> are generated in memory), your repository can cache and return the details. Either way, this should be your Repository responsibility, not the Controller's.

Comment: Hi, This is giving all the entries. How to get only the unique values?  VehDriverList.Distinct() is not working for me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So you have `Vehicles` and `Drivers`, and every `Driver` drives exactly one `Vehicle`, namely the Vehicle that the foreign key `VehicleId` refers to.

In theory there could be more Drivers on the same Vehicle. For instance if Driver [10] and Driver [11] both have a foreign key VehicleId = [20]. In that case, both Drivers will drive Vehicl [20].

In database terms, you will say that there is a one-to-many relation between Vehicles and Drivers: every Vehicle is driven by zero or more Drivers, every Driver drives exactly one Vehicle, namely the one and only Vehicle that the foreign key refers to.

If you have a one-to-many relation, like Customers with their zero or more Orders, Schools with their Students, or in your case Vehicles with their Drivers, there may be two kind of queries:

- Give me all items with their zero or more sub-items; all Vehicles, each Vehicle with their Drivers
- Give me subItems, each subItem with its one and only parent items; all Drivers, each Driver with its one and only Vehicle that he Drives.

In the latter case you'll use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-5.0). In the first case you'll use one of the overloads of[Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin).

I almost always use the overload with a parameter `resultSelector`, which gives me the opportunity to precisely define which properties I want from the Drivers and the  Vehicles.

### Join: Drivers, each Driver with his Vehicle

```
var drivers = Drivers.Join(Vehicles, // Join Drivers and Vehicles

    driver => driver.VehicleId,      // from every driver take the foreign key
    vehicle => vehicle.Id,           // from every vehicle take the primary key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every driver with his one and only
    // matching vehicle, make one new:
    (driver, vehicle) => new
    {
         // Select the Driver properties that you plan to use:
         Id = driver.Id,
         Name = driver.Name,
         ...

         Vehicle = new
         {
             Id = vehicle.Id,
             Type = vehicle.Type,
             ...
         }
});
```

You won't get Vehicles that have no Drivers at all. After all: you are querying Drivers, not Vehicles!

My advice would be not to select the foreign key. You already know that it equals the primary key of the Vehicle.

### GroupJoin: Vehicles, each Vehicle with its zero or more Drivers

```
var vehiclesWithTheirDrivers= Vehicles.GroupJoin(Drivers

    vehicle => vehicle.Id,           // from every vehicle take the primary key
    driver => driver.VehicleId,      // from every driver take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every vehicle with its zero or more
    // drivers, make one new:
    (vehicle, driversOfThisVehicle) => new
    {
         // Select the Vehicle properties that you plan to use:
         Id = vehicle.Id,
         Type = vehicle.Type,
         ...

         Drivers = driversOfThisVehicle.Select(driver => new
         {
             // Select the Driver properties that you plan to use:
             Id = driver.Id,
             Name = driver.Name,
             ...

             // not needed, you already know the value:
             // VehicleId = driver.VehicleId,
          })
          .ToList(),
  });
```